# Realm and tableView iOS app using Objective-C: Thread 1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=, address=0x30)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, realm

I wanted to load my realm database into my tableView and my code is like this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "customCell.h"
#import "Person.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property RLMRealm *realm;
@property RLMResults *person;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize realm, person;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    Person *one;
    one.firstName = @"Allen";
    one.lastName = @"X";
    realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    [realm beginWriteTransaction];
    [realm addObject:one];
    [realm commitWriteTransaction];
    self.person = [Person allObjects];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:   (NSInteger)section{
    return [person count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";
    customCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.firstName.text = [self.person[indexPath.row] firstName];
    cell.lastName.text = [self.person[indexPath.row] lastName];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

I think the Person.h can be omitted here.
So every time I compile and run it, it'll say like this:
[image]

I tried a thousand times and never figured out why. Can some one help this poor rookie?

So after following your advice, the red error is gone but a green one comes. Here it is:

[image]

Comment: Remove the breakpoint in person.h

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized and allocated the Person object, and then you are trying to populate its properties so you are obviously getting an access violation.

Change to something like this:

```
Person *one = [Person new];
one.firstName = @"Allen";
one.lastName = @"X";
```

Comment: Please post another question, this not a forum but a question answer format, anyway you are still trying to access a not correctly initialized object